# Media storage browser field in magento2

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I'm currently trying to create (or find how to) a field to display the Media browser (or media storage manager) in admin Edit on a custom module.

Type file / image work fine, but it could be much more efficient if this button open the panel like in the wysiwyg. I see the javascript call in the wysiwyg

```
javascript:openBrowser('filebrowser','src', 'media','media_media_browser_callback');
```

but i didn't find a way to call that out of this field.

Answer (score 1):

So, since i needed it, i made it :
https://github.com/Losams/Magento-2-Media-storage-field/

A new magento2 element form field to display what i want only.
It's a first thing, not really beautiful but it work. Feel free to use it.

Comment: Hi, have you found a way to add this through a uicomponent xml layout?

Comment: Hi, 
So you want to display the img of the media storage in your grid that's it ? (I assumed that because /view/adminhtml/ui_component/***.xml si for grid)

You have to create a new class in order to format datas, then, you call this class on your uicomponent. 

I made an update on my repository, check this and tell me if it's clear.
https://github.com/Losams/Magento-2-Media-storage-field/